# Why can't Windows 7 find downloaded driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

Why after downloading what I believe are the correct PLC6 drivers for an HP 4515x can't `Add New Printer` locate the driver in the downloaded directory?

We have a networked HP 4515x. I've downloaded the correct driver for PLC6. I have checked to see that Windows 7 is indeed running on 64-bit hardware and is showing that by right-clicking on `Start --> My Computer --> Properties`.

While adding the printer, I get a message saying you don't have the driver, and the default place to look after pressing `OK` is the directory into which the driver is downloaded. `Add Printer` will not select the .INF file, and anything I blindly select won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you right-click on the `.inf` file and select `Install` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the driver you downloaded?

http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software12/COL40842/ds-99374-3/upd-pcl6-x64-5.5.0.12834.exe

found on this site:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3558896

Comment: Don't know. I went to an official HP page and downloaded PLC6, 64-bit Windows 7 for an HP 4515x.

Comment: The first link is to the universal printer driver, which it sounds like you did get. Just check to see if what you downloaded was actually the 'upd-pcl6-x64-5.5.0.12834.exe' file as specified. Worst case scenario, you can try another model printer that uses a similar "universal" printer driver, just a different version, and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have had an HP driver with same issue.  Turned out HP posted the wrong driver.  Spent almost two hours on phone before they figured this out.  We received a CD from HP that resolved the issue but wasted hours on this simple issue